# Designing User Interface in QT designer and connecting with QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, plugins, qt, pyqt

I am trying to input a excel file into QGIS from the QT designer User Interface.

I want to select the attribute list from the UI and display the thematic maps from the selected attribute list to the UI.

As i am new to this field i don't know how to establish connection between QT designer and QGIS to display the maps on UI.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at this tutorial: http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html. You can also look at the source code of plugins similar to what you want to achieve.